# Function expression of ng-class gets called on ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am facing a problem in ng-class.

When i click on the the button, click function gets called may times(number of element in ng-repleat).
[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mgPGS/515/)

```js
var myModule = angular.module('app', []);

myModule.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.num = [1, 2];
  $scope.getClass = function(a) {
    console.log("class set");
    return true;
  };
  $scope.clicked = function() {
    console.log("clicked");

  };

});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="n in num" ng-class="{'red':getClass('red')}" ng-click="clicked()">{{n}}</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing unusual here. When you click, you potentially triggers a change in the model and therefore angular triggers a digest cycle.

As the `getClass` function is bound to an `ng-class` directive, the function is evaluated during the digest.

Note: you could avoid the `ng-class` being recalculated by using *one-time* binding, which is an angular 1.3+ feature:

```
ng-class="::{'red':getClass('red')}"
```

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x843hu5k/)**

Answer (score 0):

The functions in partials are called with each `$digest` cycle and each triggered `$digest` runs twice

I've updated your fiddle with a dummy function that triggers `$digest`

http://jsfiddle.net/mgPGS/516/

```
$scope.testDigest = function(){
  $timeout(angular.noop)
}
```

if you click on digest button every function will be triggered twice, if you use angular 1.3+ you can use `::` for one time binding